# Синхронность в Django 4.2 ASGI

Tags: django

Ранее писал приложение на Django 3.2.19 на ASGI с Django Channels, и без проблем удавалось держать его по умолчанию синхронным. То есть, у меня вьюшки все в основном синхронные, в одном потоке, а какие нужно - делал асинхронными и всё прекрасно работало.

В django 4.2 теперь у меня все вьюшки асинхронные, можно как то исправить? Код одинаков, просто на разных версиях джанги работает по разному как описал выше.

Простой пример:

```
from time import sleep as wait

def test(request):
    return HttpResponse("test")

def test2(request):
    wait(5)
    return HttpResponse("test2")
```

При запуске второй вкладке, первая не должна грузится до тех пор, пока во второй не закончится цикл. Так это работало в 3.2.19, в 4.2.6 работает асинхронно.

Comment: Ничего не понятно, синхронность или асинхронность задаётся наличием или отсутствием слова `async` перед объявлением view-функции. Что такое «теперь у меня все вьюшки асинхронные», какие именно «все вьюшки», кто их сделал асинхронными и в чём собственно проблема-то?

Comment: Всё верно, задаётся через async перед view-фунцией, так и работало всегда на версии 3.2.19, на сервере случайно установилась версия django 4.2.6. Заметил проблему с синхронностью, решил проверить. Я создал 2 view функции, в одной она пустая, а в другой я добавил time.sleep для того, чтобы проверить наличие синхронности.

В django 3.2.19 во время выполнения time.sleep, вторая вкладка без него не работала, так как ждала конца выполнения sleep. В 4.2.6 эта же функция больше ждёт, работает асинхронно. Код одинаков, версии разные.

Comment: Ну, никто вроде бы не обещал, что синхронные вьюхи будут запускаться строго в одном потоке. Более того, они и **не должны** запускаться в одном потоке — именно для того, чтобы всякие sleep'ы не блокировали работу других вьюх

Comment: @andreymal ну вот и произошла проблема, что на проекте после появился баг после этого именно в синхронных функциях, на что они были рассчитаны. Что можно сделать чтобы сделать работу как в 3.2.19?

Comment: Переделывайте свои синхронные функции так, чтобы они **не** были на это рассчитаны

Comment: каким образом? Обычное выполнение функций, но и за того что как будто пропала вся синхронность - произошёл баг. Там нечего переделывать вовсе, проверка ORM и запись

Comment: Никто нигде никогда не гарантировал никакой синхронности, даже без ASGI. То, что вы полагались на какую-то синхронность — это ваша ошибка

Comment: Повторю, как тогда что делать для адекватной работы? При чём тут загвоздка кого тут ошибка.

Comment: Выяснить причину, которая мешает адекватной работе без какой-то там «синхронности», и устранить её

Comment: Тем временем я нашёл [конкретный коммит](https://github.com/django/django/commit/36fa071d6ebd18a61c4d7f1b5c9d17106134bd44), в котором изменилось поведение. И то, что об этом изменении даже поленились написать в release notes, ещё раз намекает на то, что никто никакую синхронизацию не гарантировал

Comment: @andreymal В чём же тогда теперь роль использовать async view-функцию, если они теперь все как в треадах работают по ощущению.

Comment: В том, что бесконечно много тредов вы не создадите, а бесконечно много async-задач — запросто (ну, настолько «бесконечно», насколько хватит оперативки)

Comment: @andreymal, ок можно хотя бы для примера разобрать только один вопрос.
Представим есть функция buy.
У юзера 400 у. валюты.
В функции buy стоит 1 проверка, если баланс > 400, то баланс обнуляется и возвращается True, в ином False.

Есть ли тут проблема в том, что юзер может каким то образом отправить 2 параллельных запроса, они могут обработаться и в каждом из них вернуть True, так как на момент запроса у него 400 у. валюты.
Должно вернуть true 1 раз, а может вывести 2. И если да, то где тут с чем как бороться?

Comment: Баланс должен храниться в базе данных, а у базы данных есть транзакции и блокировка одновременного доступа к строкам таблиц. Это по сути не имеет отношения к Django, за исключением использования [транзакций](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/transactions/) и чего-нибудь вроде [select_for_update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_for_update) для этой самой блокировки строк

Comment: (хотя, наверное, можно даже без select_for_update, если база данных умеет выкидывать ошибку при попытке одновременного изменения строки из двух разных транзакций — но это нужно уточнять в документации к базе данных, Django тут опять же почти ни при чём)

Comment: (существует ещё «optimistic locking» подход, когда вместо жёсткой блокировки просто в момент записи проверяется, что значение со временем не изменилось — типа `UPDATE user SET balance = 0 WHERE user_id = 777 AND balance = 400` — и вот тут к сожалению Django очень даже при чём, потому что в нём так сделать невозможно без сторонних костылей)